# How realistic are the dogfight scenes in Dunkirk

Tags: realism, historical-accuracy, dunkirk

I saw the film Dunkirk yesterday with some friends and thoroughly enjoyed it.  One of my friends had some quibbles with the dogfight scenes, however.   How realistic are they?  Any reliable sources related to the points below would be much appreciated.

- https://www.quora.com/How-long-do-a-Spitfires-guns-keep-firing-during-battle says that Spitfires carried enough ammunition to fire for a total of less than 30 seconds. In the film, Tom Hardy's character seems to fire for much more than that (but I'm not sure -- I wasn't counting).  How much creative license is the film using here?  What's Tom Hardy's total firing time?
- Related point:  if ammunition was limited in reality, you'd think pilots would be worried not only about their fuel gauge, but also about how many rounds they had left in their guns.  Is that right?  Did Spitfires even have ammunition gauges?  If so, do we ever see it in the film?  Tom Hardy's character spends tons of time thinking about how much fuel he has left, but does he ever look at his ammunition counter?
- Are there any confirmed cases of a Spitfire shooting down an enemy after having run out of fuel?  How plausible is this?

Comment: [The British armament was quite straightforward; both aircraft had eight belt-fed .303" (7.7mm) Browning guns mounted four in each wing outside the propeller disk.  Rate of fire was 20 rounds per second per gun (160 rps overall) and the cartridge fired ball, AP, tracer or incendiary bullets weighing around 11.3 grams at around 740 m/s (2,430 fps).  Total weight of projectiles fired was 1.8 kg (4 lb) per second. Ammunition capacity was enough for 16 seconds continuous firing in the Spitfire, slightly more in the Hurricane.](http://www.quarryhs.co.uk/BoB.htm)

Comment: You have several questions in there which probably makes this overall question too broad. I think they're interesting enough but they'd be better as **separate** questions. Some of the points though (plausibility) are not really suitable IMO as this is after all a Hollywood movie...not a documentary.

Comment: Spitfires did not have ammunition gauges, pilots had to use their experience and guess work to estimate how much ammunition they had left.  There was a famous account of a Hurricane pilot that rammed a German Bomber that was heading down the Mall towards Buckingham Palace after his guns failed.

Comment: Although later cannon armed variants were equipped with counters.

Comment: I saw the movie again (still loved it), and this time I actually counted how many times Tom Hardy pulls the trigger.  I counted ~ 18.  If each burst lasts a fraction of a second on average, that's well within the total ammunition capacity for a Spitfire.

Comment: I saw that my question was put on hold:  that's fine, as the commenters have answered essentially everyting I was asking.  No need to reopen.